# python *args not being called

Tags: python, args

I've got the following code, but I don't get any output. I ran a pdb in this, and got the following :

```
import tarfile
import sys

def hereweextract(self, *args):
    for i in args:
        try:
            f = tarfile.open(i)
            print("Extracting ", i)
            f.extractall()
            f.close()
        except tarfile.ReadError:
            sys.exit("File not a tarball, or any of .xz/.bz2/.gz archives.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hereweextract(sys.argv[1:])
```

I ran a pdb on this, and got the following :

```
>>> python ll.py file1.tar.xz file2.tar.xz
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(11)<module>()
-> def hereweextract(self, *args):
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(22)<module>()
-> if __name__ == "__main__":
(Pdb) 
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(23)<module>()
-> hereweextract(sys.argv[1:])
(Pdb) 
--Return--
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(23)<module>()->None
-> hereweextract(sys.argv[1:])
(Pdb) 
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <function _remove at 0x7f5dc8e596e0> ignored
```

I'm not sure why this is happening and what is wrong with the code. Its not even reaching the 'hereweextract()' function. I understand its something on how I'm passing the args to the function 'hereweextract()'.

Can anyone point what's wrong here and how I can correct this.

#

#

Thank you for all the answers.

This was part of a class, that's the reason why hereweextract() had a self. I totally missed it out while troubleshooting this function. Thank you all for pointing that out.

I removed it, made the suggested changes, and the function looks like this now :

```
import os
import tarfile
import sys

import pdb
pdb.set_trace()


def hereweextract(*args):
    print args
    for i in args:
        try:
        f = tarfile.open(i)
        print("Extracting ", i)
        f.extractall()
        f.close()
    except tarfile.ReadError:
        sys.exit("File not a tarball, or any of .xz/.bz2/.gz archives.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hereweextract(*sys.argv[1:])
```

For this code, I'm seeing the following pdb trace :

```
>>> python ll.py file1.tar.xz file2.tar.xz
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(11)<module>()
-> def hereweextract(*args):
(Pdb) n
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(22)<module>()
-> if __name__ == "__main__":
(Pdb) 
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(23)<module>()
-> hereweextract(*sys.argv[1:])
(Pdb) 
['file1.tar.xz', 'file2.tar.xz']
SystemExit: 'File not a tarball, or any of .xz/.bz2/.gz archives.'
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(23)<module>()
-> hereweextract(*sys.argv[1:])
(Pdb) 
--Return--
> /tmp/kk/ll.py(23)<module>()->None
-> hereweextract(*sys.argv[1:])
(Pdb) 
File not a tarball, or any of .xz/.bz2/.gz archives.
```

I understand that in `__main__`, I shouldn't be passing the args as sys.argv[1:], since its returning a list. Or am I wrong ? What should I be passing in hereweextract() ?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things wrong here. First, you're using `self` as the first argument of your function, when it's not a method in a class. Remove this; the program will not even get to the error you say it's getting.

Second, when you pass `argv[1:]` to your function, you are passing it *as a single argument:* a list containing the names of the files to be extracted. However, your function is written to accept multiple arguments, each the name of a file to be extracted. So your `args` contains a single item, the list of filenames, and when you iterate over `args` you try to open... the list of filenames, not the individual filenames. A list of filenames is not a filename, so it's not surprising that you can't open it.

You function should be defined like so. (I have also taken the liberty of cleaning up a few other things, such as improving some names and not stopping the entire program upon the first error instead of continuing to the next file.)

```
def extract_tarfiles(names):
    for name in names:
        try:
            f = tarfile.open(name)
            print("Extracting ", name)
            f.extractall()
        except tarfile.ReadError:
            print("File not a tarball, or any of .xz/.bz2/.gz archives.")
        finally:
            f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import tarfile
import sys

def hereweextract(*args):
    for i in args:
        try:
            f = tarfile.open(i)
            print("Extracting ", i)
            f.extractall()
            f.close()
        except tarfile.ReadError:
            sys.exit("File not a tarball, or any of .xz/.bz2/.gz archives.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hereweextract(*sys.argv[1:])
```

In your code content of sys.argv[1:] is assigned to self variable.

Answer (score 0):

Take out your `self` parameter from the definition of `hereweextract`. You are passing `sys.argv[1:]` which is a list of two elements (your filenames) as an argument to self. Then your `*args` tuple ends up being empty. Try printing your `args` at the beginning of `hereweextract` and you'll see that the tuple is empty.